# How does a server know which domain name was used?

Tags: networking, dns, network-programming, ip

As far as i know what we get from a dns query is a ip address. So in the end of the day if thats true we are still using ip addresses to connect the server and domains are pretty names for them.

So how does a server know which domain i used to query that ip address?
How does vhosts work an understand that if the domain data is lost during dns query?

Comment: That really depends on the application-layer protocol. Take for example HTTP, which have a header field which tells what domain name was used.

Comment: i see. And how do you access that data ?

Comment: Again, it depends on the application layer protocol. Since it's part of the application-layer, there are no "standard" functions available.

Comment: oh like the host header in http right ? @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Internet works in layers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Description_of_OSI_layers). Each layer uses different kind of parameters to do its work.

Layer 3 is typically IP aka Internet Protocol. To work it uses IP addresses, each computer has at least one to be able to discuss with another one. And there are two families in fact: version 4 and version 6.

Since multiple services can be on any given computer at some point, you need a layer on top of that, layer 4, that deals with transport. The "predominant" one is TCP aka Transport Control Protocol, but there is also UDP. TCP and UDP uses ports: a 2 bytes integer that encodes for a specific protocol.

For example, HTTP was given port number 80 (completely arbitrary), and HTTPS port 443.

The DNS, which itself uses UDP and TCP (on port 53), allows, among other things, to map a given hostname to a given IP address or multiple IP addresses. This is the typical `A` and `AAAA` records. There is also a `CNAME` record that maps one domain name to another. There also exists a `SRV` record that maps a service (which is a protocol name + a transport) to a given hostname and port number.

When one computer connects to another, its first step for all the above is to find out which IP address to use to connect to. It can use the DNS for that. Typically it will get only the IP address, but, **depending on the protocol** (layer above 4), may also get a port (if using `SRV` records).

The HTTP world does not use `SRV` records. So a browser just uses the hardcoded 80 or 443 ports, or the port number appearing in the URL.

Then we are at the transport level, let us say TCP.
The connection is done (since now the remote IP address and port are known) and the protocol above TCP, like HTTP, is free to convey any kind of extra data, such as the hostname that the client initially used (as taken from the URL) to find out the IP address.
This is done through the HTTP `host` header, see [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.23)

Note that if you do things through TLS (which conceptually sits between TCP and HTTP) there is even something else happening: SNI or Server Name Indication.

When doing the TLS handshake, so before any kind of HTTP headers or content, the client will send the final hostname desired in some specific TLS message. Why? So that the server can find which specific certificate it should answer which as otherwhise it would not be able to know which hostname is requested as this sits in some HTTP header which do not exist until the TLS handshake is finished.

A webserver will be able to see both the SNI content to find out which certificate to send back and then the `host` header to find out which `VirtualHost` (in Apache) section is relevant to the query being processed.

If you are not in HTTP world, then it all depends on the protocol used. Older protocols, like FTP, did not plan for "multihoming" at the beginning, a given IP address meant only one hostname and service for example.